# SPRING MVC getting 404 error in when you hits the submit button

Tags: spring

IN SPRING MVC
in spring mvc. i am unable to get required page,it is not showing error in console also, but it is giving 404 error in browser..

> CONSOLE-->Aug 01, 2016 10:26:09 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init INFO: The APR based
>   Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in
>   production environments was not found on the java.library.path:
>   C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
>   Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;;;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\ICLS
>   CLIENT\;C:\PROGRAM FILES\INTEL\ICLS
>   CLIENT\;C:\Windows\SYSTEM32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WBEM;C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINDOWSPOWERSHELL\V1.0\;C:\PROGRAM
>   FILES (X86)\INTEL\OPENCL SDK\2.0\BIN\X86;C:\PROGRAM FILES
>   (X86)\INTEL\OPENCL SDK\2.0\BIN\X64;C:\PROGRAM FILES\INTEL\INTEL(R)
>   MANAGEMENT ENGINE COMPONENTS\DAL;C:\PROGRAM FILES\INTEL\INTEL(R)
>   MANAGEMENT ENGINE COMPONENTS\IPT;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\INTEL(R)
>   MANAGEMENT ENGINE COMPONENTS\DAL;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\INTEL(R)
>   MANAGEMENT ENGINE COMPONENTS\IPT;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth
>   Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth
>   Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions
>   for PHP\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;. Aug 01, 2016
>   10:26:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] Aug 01, 2016 10:26:09 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] Aug 01, 2016 10:26:09 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization
>   processed in 838 ms Aug 01, 2016 10:26:09 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting
>   service Catalina Aug 01, 2016 10:26:09 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
>   Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 Aug 01, 2016 10:26:10 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor INFO:
>   Deploying configuration descriptor
>   D:\Springs\WORK_SPACE.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\demoMVC.xml
>   Aug 01, 2016 10:26:10 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin WARNING:
>   [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to
>   'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:demoMVC' did not find a matching
>   property. Aug 01, 2016 10:26:11 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: No Spring
>   WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath Aug 01, 2016
>   10:26:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO:
>   Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher' Aug 01, 2016
>   10:26:12 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
>   initServletBean INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization
>   started Aug 01, 2016 10:26:12 AM
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext
>   prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace
>   'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Aug 01 10:26:12 IST 2016];
>   root of context hierarchy Aug 01, 2016 10:26:12 AM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader
>   loadBeanDefinitions INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/kool-servlet.xml] Aug 01, 2016
>   10:26:13 AM
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter
>   initControllerAdviceCache INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice:
>   WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date
>   [Mon Aug 01 10:26:12 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy Aug 01, 2016
>   10:26:13 AM
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter
>   initControllerAdviceCache INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice:
>   WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date
>   [Mon Aug 01 10:26:12 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy Aug 01, 2016
>   10:26:13 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
>   initServletBean INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization
>   completed in 1599 ms Aug 01, 2016 10:26:13 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] Aug 01, 2016 10:26:13 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] Aug 01, 2016 10:26:13 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in
>   4303 ms

Comment: you should upload your code not the exception message

Comment: index.jsp<html>
<body>

<form action="add" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="t1">
 <input type="text" name="t2">
 <input type="submit">


</form>


</body>
</html>

Comment: @shan edit the question and post the code there

Answer (score 0):

```
index.jsp

<html>
<body>

<form action="add" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="t1">
 <input type="text" name="t2">
 <input type="submit">


</form>


</body>
</html>

controller.java

package com.test;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;


    @Controller
public class addController {




      @RequestMapping("/add")
      @ResponseBody
    public String add()
    {
        return "display.jsp";
    }
}



web.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml -->



<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

     <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>    


  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

      <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/kool-servlet.xml</param-value>  
      </init-param>

      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>


test-servlet.xml

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.test" />

        <mvc:annotation-driven />

    </beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling a page display.jsp which does not exists. change display.jsp to index.jsp in your controller and it should work, or change the view name index.jsp to display.jsp.